# EJB bean breaks the keycloak auth-method

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, keycloak

In [this GitHub project](https://github.com/fbielejec/keycloak-demo) I have modified the basic keycloak example by adding a webservice bean annotated with WebContext. This results in the KEYCLOAK as auth-method being overwritten as BASIC. Note that the bean isn't called anywhere it is *just* on the classpath. To reproduce check it out and deploy following the readme instructions.

Is this a desired behaviour?

Comment: This is now reported as https://issues.jboss.org/projects/KEYCLOAK/issues/KEYCLOAK-3966?filter=allopenissues

Comment: The first thing they will do is ask you to confirm the behaviour with the latest WildFly and KeyCloak versions...

Comment: This is the latest keycloak and keycloak-wildfly- adapter (2.4.0). Wildfly itself is in ver. 9.0.2 but the adapter is supposed to work with 9/10.

Comment: Well, there may be a bug 9.0.2 that is not present in 10.1.0. If the latter still does not work and it's a WildFly bug, then any fix will be in 10.x or later.